# How to put multiple non math subscripts?

Tags: subscripts

I would like to get the following expression in Latex : 
[image]

I tried it as followed:

```
GSK_{n,z,t} = \frac{P_{n,t}^{N,Y}}{\sum_{n \in z}^{\infty} P_{n,t}^{N,Y}}
```

but this doesn't work. Any idea how it should be written ?

Comment: The question title says "non math" and yet the image shows "math" subscripts.  I'm confused.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code works, of course you need to put it in math environment ...

Comment: If you don't want it in an equation type environment, you can use $\displaystyle ... $.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathit{XYZ}_{a,b,c}^{\gamma} = \dfrac{\mathit{XYZ}_{a,b,c}^{\gamma}}{\sum_{a \in b} \mathit{XYZ}_{a,b,c}^{\gamma}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Not related to the actual question:* I assume that `XYZ` is one variable and not three variables multiplied. Therefore I used \mathit so that tey are one unit. If someone has a better idea, please leave a comment or change the code here.

*Non-math stuff in equations:* If you are looking for **text in the equation**, try `\text{a b c}`. `\text` is provided by the `amsmath` package (`mathtools` loads `amsmath` in this example).